# How can i set a cronjob with WP CLI for the WebP Express Plugins to convert the images

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

In WP CLI I can run `wp webp-express convert` and it works
But how can get this to work in a cronjob?

This was one of the things I tried: `wp cron event schedule webp_express --webp-express --convert now hourly`
but with this the webp express plugin do not start anything.

my resources:
https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-express
https://support.pagely.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031050071-Managing-WordPress-Cron-Events-with-WP-CLI

Comment: Two different things. Cron jobs are independent of WordPress. They run on the server. So you log in to your server, find out how to setup a cron job, and then let this cronjob run any command you want at any interval you want. For example let this cronjob run `wp webp-express convert`.

Comment: Thanks and yes I know that a cron is not a Wordpress thing. But how kann I run `wp webp-express convert` in a working way? In the meantime I put it in a function and try to run the command with shell_exec() and exec() but this do nothing.

Comment: Your cron tab could contain this for example (after you created an alias to the wp-cli command): `15 * * * * cd /path/to/wordpress && wp webp-express convert > /dev/null 2>&1` to convert images every full hour plus 15 minutes (11:15, 12:15, 13:15 etc.).

Comment: @leymannx Thanks but I got only an "command not found" form the cron-system. 
I also tested the wp --info to have a more basic command.
With SSH I can use the commands from my path to the WP installation (/path/to/wordpress)

Comment: Try either to reinstall WP-CLI in a way that every user can run the command or execute it directly like `php /path/to/wp-cli.phar webp-express convert`.